# Oracle ORDS - How to bypass 404 error on Standalone

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-ords

I have been trying to establish a connection to use ORDS and was successful once, but now I am receiving a 404 error when I try to connect to my database on ORDS.

When I first log onto http://127.0.0.1:1521/ords/sql-developer, I receive the following messages:

The service is disabled in this environment 
Stack Trace
DisabledException [statusCode=404, reasons=[The service is disabled in this environment]]

---

### This is what I've tried:

java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=C:\Users\ip4169\Desktop\ORDS\ords -jar ords.war validate

### -> Completed validating Oracle REST Data Services version 19.4.0.r3521226.  Elapsed time: 00:00:15.700[CHECK]

java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=C:\Users\ip4169\Desktop\ORDS\ords -jar ords.war standalone 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuhJ2.png)->
oejs.Server:main: Started @8299ms [CHECK]

---

I've checked my TNSORA.net files and see my database information is included inside.

Here is the ORDS error page:
If someone could please assist me through this I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 5):

The 404 was happening at login time while trying to access SQL Developer Web for a user.

Two things to check:

- the database connection pool is correctly configured
- the schema is rest enabled

In this case the pool wasn't being established at startup because the ORDS_PUBLIC_USER password wasn't correct - ORDS couldn't create database connections.

Once the database user password was reset to what was defined in the pool config XML file, an ords restart showed the pool being established. *Check the stdout when starting ords for errors!*

If on the other hand you're getting errors trying to access the App in general at the /ords/sql-developer url, then -

You need to ensure SQL Developer Web is enabled.

Add these lines to your defaults.xml file and restart ords

```
<entry key="feature.sdw">true</entry>
<entry key="restEnabledSql.active">true</entry>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff! Big fan first of all, and thanks for getting back to me fast! I just checked my Defaults.XML file and I have those entries already saved in, have restarted multiple times already.

Comment: ah man, i read your post too fast - your port is wrong, see my updated answer

Comment: No problem! I used 8080 instead of 1521, and it doesn't connect me but 1521 gets me to the sign in page. Does my TNSnames.ora port have to be the ORDS listener (8080) or the DATABASE listener (1521) ? I switched from 1521 to 8080 and I still can't connect as localhost:8080

Comment: there's no correlation on listener port and ords port...go to the standalone.properties file and check the jetty.port entry, that number will be the port used for ords in standalone mode

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the ports, checked out the standalone.properties and the jetty.port = 1521, I changed it to 8080 and received the following - The request could not be mapped to any database. Check the request URL is correct, and that URL to database mappings have been correctly configured, so at this point should I refer to the Oracle ORDS Mapping document?

Comment: when you ran the installer, it should have prompted you for database information for setting up the default connection pool...do you have your installation log handy?

Comment: Yes I have the installation log on ords_install_core_2020_03-12. Should I post it for you to see?

Comment: How about we do a zoom call on Monday and we'll get you going, email me jeff.d.smith at Oracle